# Creating sound when releasing a button

Tags: python, pygame

I've been stuck with this for a very long time now. I have a button class. You can already select the button, click the button, and release the button (which causes a event to happen). I want to put sound for when you release the button, but I just can't. I don't understand how you're supposed to do that, I've tried everything. In other words, I want to make sure that the mouse is held down when it's already selecting the button, then if it releases in that position, a attribute called `release` will toggle to True for one frame. Then I can check if release is True, then I'd play the sound. My question: What condition do I need to check to have the `release` attribute toggle to True for one frame? This is my code structure:

```py
# "mouse_down" is a global for when the mouse is being held down
# "clicked" is a global variable for the first frame at which the mouse is held down
# I also have a "release" global variable for the frame that the mouse stops clicking, this variable isn't currently being used.

class Button:
    def __init__(self, pos, size, font, text, colors):
        """
        colors[n]
        
        0: fill   unselected
        1: border unselected
        2: text   unselected
        3: fill   selected
        4: border selected
        5: text   selected
        6: fill   clicked
        7: border clicked
        8: text 
        """

        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
        self.font = font
        self.text = text
        self.colors = colors
        self.selected = False
        self.clicked = False
        self.release= False

    def update(self):
        # If the mouse is hovering on the button
        if (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] > button.pos[0] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < button.pos[0] + button.size[0]) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > button.pos[1] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < button.pos[1] + button.size[1]):
            self.selected = True
            
            if clicked: 
                self.clicked = True

            if not mouse_down:
                self.clicked = False

        else:
            self.selected = False
            self.clicked = False
```

Now  just to clarify, let's assume I hold down the click button with my mouse, drag it to the button's position, then let go, the release attribute shouldn't toggle on since the mouse needs to be placed on the button to begin with.

Comment: Do you mean `release` button?

Comment: That is a more accurate name, yes

Comment: Do you realize that `pygame` already has the ability to generate events when the mouse is pressed and released?  It seems to me that you're reinventing the wheel here.  Where do "clicked" and "mouse_down" come from?

Comment: I got those from a event loop. The thing is I can't just completely rely on these variables, there's more to it but I can't figure out what that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use [`pygame.rect.collidepoint`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) to get if the mouse collides with the button instead of

```
if (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] > button.pos[0] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] < button.pos[0] + button.size[0]) and (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] > button.pos[1] and pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] < button.pos[1] + button.size[1]):
```

How it works:

- Main loop: get the `MOUSEBUTTONUP` event (occurs when you release a mouse button)
- Send this event to the button
- Also send if the actual mouse **click** (`MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`) occurred in the button
- If both events are True, then play the sound

In the button class:

- `__init__`: generate the collide zone + the text `Surface`
- `update`: draw the rect, then the text centered, then check if collision + event + pressed on button

#### Class `Button`:

```py
class Button:
    def __init__(self, pos, size, font, text, color):
        self.rect = Rect(pos, size) # 
        self.text = font.render(text, 0, color) # text surface
        self.button_down_on = False

    def update(self, release_event):
        # draw the button
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (100, 100, 100), self.rect)
        width, height = self.text.get_size()
        screen.blit(self.text, (int(self.rect.x + self.rect.width / 2 - width / 2),
                                int(self.rect.y + self.rect.height / 2 - height / 2)))

        # check collisions
        if release_event and self.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
            if self.button_down_on: # if the mouse began to press on this button
                print('play sound')
```

#### Script

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

button = Button((10, 10), (200, 40), pygame.font.SysFont('consolas', 20), 'Test', (127, 255, 255))

running = True
while running:
    release_event = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # check if the click begin on a button
            button.button_down_on = button.rect.collidepoint(event.pos)
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            release_event = True # send this event to Button.update

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    button.update(release_event)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: As I clarified in my question, I **don't** want the sound to play if I click down on the mouse while not hovering on the button, drag it towards the button (while still holding down), then letting go of my click. In your code, it will still create a sound.

Comment: This solution seems to be continuously repeating `'Play sound'`. Instead of having it print for one frame.

Comment: I does not. Don't use the last part, I will remove it. But the first part plays a sound when 1. the moue releases **and** 2. the mouse click was on the button.